# Binary tree, delete the root

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I want to delete the first name, which is the root in the binary tree.

```
void remove() // cpp file
patient person;
bool found = false;
tree.RetrieveItemRoot(person, found);
tree.DeleteItem(person);
```

Template //.h file

```
void HeapType::Delete(HeapNode*& tree, patient item, bool& found)
{
    if (tree == NULL) {
        found = false;  // item is not found.
        return;
    }

    Delete(tree->left, item, found);
    if (found) return;
    Delete(tree->right, item, found);
    if (found) return;

    if (item.firstName == tree->info.firstName) {
        deleteNode(tree);
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Template

```
void HeapType::DeleteItem(patient item)
{
    bool found = false;
    Delete(root, item, found);
}
```

Template

```
void HeapType::modify(HeapNode*& tree, patient item)
{
    item.gravity = new item.gravity;
}
```

Template

```
void HeapType::modifyItem(patient item)
{
    Delete(root, item);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information and context on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have a function called remove but my function ask the name of the person I want to remove. but now I want to create a function for remove the first name of the tree  (the root ) and each time I ll call this function , it will delete the first name of the tree. each node contain (a name and an integer number (1 to 5).

Comment: struct patient
{
 string firstName;
 int gravity;
};

Comment: template<class ItemType>
void  HeapType<ItemType>::Retrieve(HeapNode<ItemType>* tree, ItemType& item, bool& found)
{
 if (tree == NULL) {
  found = false; // item is not found.
        return;
    }

    Retrieve(tree->left, item, found);
    if (found) return;

 Retrieve(tree->right, item, found);
    if (found) return;

    if (item.firstName == tree->info.firstName) {
     item.gravity = tree->info.gravity;
     found = true;
    }
}

template <class ItemType>
void HeapType<ItemType>::RetrieveItem(ItemType& item, bool& found)
{
 Retrieve(root, item, found);
}

Comment: sorry I try to put the different template for retrieve